# Hey, Im having a dream and it's the third time that iam dreaming

Tags: sex, husband-wife, dream, sexuality, cheating

Im having a dream where a unknown person kidnaps ne with his magic and later we are doing sex and i am enjoying in my dream and later we stop and i see a little bit blood on my vagina. Im married and i have a husband . Don't think about this thing in reality and I feel very guilty for watching these dreams please if you know anything how to stop these dreams tell me

Comment: Recite ayat-ul-kursi before sleep. These type of dreams are shetan influenced.

Comment: You have no control on dream. It will automatically be stopped. Don't worry

Answer (score 0):

Recite dua and ayat-ul-kursi before going to sleep. If possible recite a page or two of quran before going to sleep daily.

If it becomes more frequent you should seek advice from a scholar.